# Trigonometric Interpolation using the Discrete Fourier Transform

Tags: python, interpolation, dft

I am trying to approximate a function using the Discrete Fourier Transform, being given `2M+1` values of the function.

I've seen a few different expression for the coefficients and the approximation, but the ones I was originally trying were (12) and (13) as in http://www.chebfun.org/docs/guide/guide11.html

<sup>(I apologize for the link, but apparently Stack Overflow does not support Latex.)</sup>

I have a function for computing the approximation given the coefficients and another to calculate the coefficients, but it also returns this previous function. I've tested with some values but the results weren't close at all. I compared both of them with the `numpy.fft.fft`: the coefficients didn't match and passing the FFT to the first function did not result in a good approximation as well, so the coefficients aren't the only problem.

Here is my code:

```py
def model(cks, x):
    n = len(cks)
    assert(n%2 == 1)
    M = (n-1)//2
    def soma(s):
        soma = 0
        for i in range(n):
            m = -M + i
            soma += cks[i]*cmath.exp(1j*m*s)
        return soma
    soma = np.vectorize(soma)
    return soma(x)

def fourier(y):
    n = len(y)
    assert(n%2 == 1)
    M = (n-1)//2
    def soma(k):
        soma = 0
        for i in range(n):
            t =  2*math.pi*i/n
            soma += y[i]*cmath.exp(-1j*k*t)
        return (1/n)*soma
    cks = np.zeros(n, dtype='complex')
    for i in range(n):
        j = -M + i
        cks[i] = soma(j)
    return cks, (lambda x: model(cks,x))
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I understand your code, but it looks to me like you have a forward and an inverse DFT there. One of those doesn't use `pi`, but it should.

If you're interested in obtaining interpolating samples, you can apply the DFT, pad it with zeros, then compute the inverse DFT (I'm using MATLAB code, because that is what I know, but I think it's fairly easy to read):

```matlab
f = randn(1,21);                     % an input signal to be interpolated
F = fft(f);                          % forward DFT
F = fftshift(F);                     % shift zero frequency to middle of array
F = [zeros(1,60),F,zeros(1,60)];     % pad with equal number of zeros on both sides
F = ifftshift(F);                    % shift zero frequency back to first array element
fi = ifft(F) * length(F)/length(f); % inverse DFT, normalize
                                     % `fi` is the interpolated `f`

% plotting
x = linspace(1,length(fi)+1,length(f)+1);
x = x(1:end-1);
plot(x,f,'x');
xi = 1:length(fi);
hold on
plot(xi,fi);
```

[image]

If you feel like you need to implement the DFT and inverse DFT from scratch, know that you can [implement the latter using the former](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Expressing_the_inverse_DFT_in_terms_of_the_DFT).

If you want to create a continuous function as a summation of shifted sine functions, follow [the equation for the Fourier series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series#Definition), with *A_n* and *Φ_n* given by the amplitude and phase of the elements of the DFT.